# How disable `ctrl + pageup` shortcut in Thunderbird left pane?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I am used to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> in many of my applications (firefox, terminal, thunderbird, ...) to navigate between tabs.

This worked fine in Thunderbird (to switch between emails and calendars mainly) until a recent update : when the focus is on the left pane showing my email accounts typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> scrolls down or up **inside** the folder pane instead of switching tabs.

I already spent hours trying to fix that without success mainly trying ad-ons. So my question is : does anyone know how can I remove this scrolling shortcut on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> in the folder pane ?

Comment: Is **NumLock** on? Ctrl+PgUp and Dn work as you expect, changing tab, only when Num is not Locked.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik with or without `NumLock` on, the behaviour is the same for me : If something is selected in the folder pane and it has focus, then the shortcut scrolls into this pane instead of moving to next/previous tab.

Comment: Workaround: hit ```ctrl+k``` then ```ctrl+pgup``` / ```ctrl+pgdn```

Comment: @1NN Thank you for the workaround. It's no perfect, but better than nothing :) So I guess you are able to reproduce the behaviour I described ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior at all : Ctrl+PgUp/Dn for me behave on both sides the same as PgUp/Dn. Ctrl has no effect. After Ctrl+K neither has any effect at all. Do you have any installed add-on that explains this behavior? Try it perhaps in [Troubleshoot Mode Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-mode-thunderbird).

Comment: @harrymc Troubleshoot does not change anything. `ctrl+pgup` should according to official documentation switch to next tab. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-thunderbird?redirectslug=keyboard-shortcuts&redirectlocale=en-US#w_moving-around-thunderbird

Comment: Yes I can recroduce what you describe. I'm on TB 102.4.2

Comment: have you tried tbkeys ? https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/

Comment: @1NN Yes I did. Without success. Did you ?

Comment: @1NN I finally succeeded with `tbkeys`, thank you very much. Do you mind to add an answer so that I can validate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [tbkeys addon](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/).

The plugin is aimed at power users, so you'll need to [consult the github page](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys) to check how to set up everything but adding these two lines in main key bindings setting should do the trick :

```
    "ctrl+pagedown": "window.document.getElementById('tabmail-tabs').advanceSelectedTab(1, true)",
    "ctrl+pageup": "window.document.getElementById('tabmail-tabs').advanceSelectedTab(-1, true)"
```